# How do effective FULL removal of TOR from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, security, proxy, privacy

After installing TOR, privoxy & anonproxy on my system, I found out that some functions on my browser had become unavailable and I didn't found the way to solve all the issues there, so I decided to simply remove the services from, in order to recover full original usage of normal internet navigation -and continue the overcome with it-.

_ *Later on, however, I've noticed that my internet connection slowed down so much that a lot of times -more than once per session- it becomes simply unusable too frequently (first, the browser lags too much and download of pages slows down a lot then disconnection happens by itself, here if I make a bad move on this phase the whole system simply chrash, so I always have to reboot the computer on and on again [Im full of it indeed]).*

So (*Please help as Im beginner or something*) following would be the **1st question**: 
**After running**  `netstat --tcp` **on Ubuntu 1204, Is it normal to see many connections like this?:**

```
tcp        0      0 100.100.0.100:53812     customer-TOR-200-3:http ESTABLISHED
```

- I get as many as 20 of these entries (as least) on different ports
  every time as I'm just getting connected to internet.

_ *In case these too many such connections ain't any as normal at all, then I imagine some kind of remains still left from TOR on my system, (as I had found out just after anonproxy or privoxy removal (just cant recall which one exactly)), and, If it's the case I guess TOR leaves then a kind of configuration or IDKW to continue using it as a node to serve TOR-customers and thats causing probably some broadband pollution and the more-than-5 reboots per session when overload my search.*

I may sound a little bit absolute selfish but Id like being able to use the limited broadband I've got just a little bit looser, just some like before, given I'm not even using TOR at all, or thats what I think since I did `apt-get autoremove --purge` it.

So, **2nd question**: **How can I make sure TOR is completely off my system alltogether with its trails?**

Since I've been google-ing "*completely remove tor*" and such, but all I get there is only about its installation instructions, also I visited torproject site but that only means reading more manuals, I dont know If I maybe missed something at uninstallation either else so thats why I decided to enquire here.

_ *Mainly, problem is that since I cant make sure if TOR-stuff are or not involved, I cant tell if Im being attacked or what, yet Ive been attempting to learn how to close all ports or fix them stealth or something, as to set dhcp to dynamic at least, but nowadays I simply can find guidelines nowhere to configure a more secure Ubuntu 12.04 system, alltogether with the fact that most of its security options have changed, and looks like this happens now more often than before. This such behaviour wasnt the case before so I know this is but normal, I were able to see several large videos online at same time and at most it would only result, very rare ocassions, on a freezed browser for a short moment, then I knew I was overwhelming it. Now, it affects the whole system at use.*

I think all of these connections are due TOR-trails, not system-default normal ones and theyre just polluting the usage of my own connection, even one of all these -maybe- 'does something'. Id like someone could enlight out more about this; **full effective removal of TOR** or about **why all of these connections from TOR customer**, even **how to set a DYNAMIC DHCP on Ubuntu 12.04** and **a effective and/or simple way to close ALL unused ports** but those for internet search which is only what I generally do use, I think that would help to clean up my traffic and maybe speed up internet usage as to detect more clearly if unrequested connections are being held.

- **Question indeed is about getting TOR effective full removal, if** `apt-get autoremove --purge` **was wrong and/or
  insufficient, nevertheless all other points' clearence will be pretty
  appreciated of course. Thank you. Cheers.**

Comment: Why `autoremove`? Why not just `sudo apt-get purge tor`?

Comment: @terdon I just didnt know if there where any dependencies with tor that were needed to be removed and I thought adding autoremove*code* would cover the task at once, IDK. It's the first time I install tor as also the first I remove it. :|. BTW, Could you tell if the entries I mentioned are just normal on connections?

Comment: No experience with `tor`, sorry. The problem should go away if you run `apt-get purge` though.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem, but am not sure, if I list all the necessary steps, therefore firstly, I describe what *exactly* I did, and then try to narrow it down to what is *necessary*.

### What I have done

Last night, I installed Tor client on Ubuntu 14.10 i386 (ubuntu) from official ppa. Set up the Firefox Developer Edition 37.0a2 (2015-01-24) (ff) according to recommended settings. Worked fine.

But then I wanted either modify ff to make it my own tor browser (but unfortunately, I have found no changed settings list or diff between Firefox ESR and Tor Browser) or at least install the  official Tor Browser. So I have installed the Tor Browser using `$ sudo apt-get install tor vidalia deb.torproject.org-keyring`. Configured tor in vidalia as a relay and all worked fine.

Then I went to bed, leaving the notebook turned on, tor & vidalia still on while I hard switched off the WiFi (i.e., with a physical switch).

In the morning, I turned the WiFi on, and I could not browse the Web. So i ran `4 ping 8.8.8.8` and 100% loss, or at least 75% loss. Doubled-checked physical/hardware network connection between router and notebook, checked the router settings—all were set as they should be.

Then I cannot recall exact procedure I used, but I do know that I have multiple times uninstalled, installed, and reinstalled the `tor vidalia deb.torproject.org-keyring`, purged these packages, and rebooted the notebook, but no adequate Internet connection was recreated.

Then I have searched, what are dependencies of tor. Uninstalled `tor vidalia deb.torproject.org-keyring` and also the dependencies `tor vidalia tor-dbg torsocks torchat tor-geo* tor-arm redsocks onioncat obfsproxy anon-proxy`, removed `~/.vidalia` and rebooted my notebook. Now I have got the Net connection.

Though my former output of `netstat` had more addresses, the recent output still has (I think) more addresses then necessary. But I am not sure, for (1) I cannot remember how it used to look before installation of tor (afaik, I never used that command b4) and (2) I do not really understand, what the output does mean. Here is my recent output:

### Necessary steps

1. `$ sudo apt-get purge tor vidalia tor-dbg torsocks torchat tor-geo* tor-arm redsocks onioncat obfsproxy anon-proxy deb.torproject.org-keyring`
2. `$ sudo reboot`